# Dropdown Menu isn't Working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

Currently having an issue where my navigation and dropdowns aren't working on iOS devices, specifically iPhone.

When the user clicks a nav item, that has children, I toggle a class on the parent container, which displays the dropdown.

Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-365" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-365 nav-open"><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="http://localhost:8888/beulah/about/im-new/">I’m New</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-166" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-166"><a href="http://localhost:8888/beulah/about/membership/">Membership</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43"><a href="http://localhost:8888/beulah/about/core-values/">Core Values</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://localhost:8888/beulah/about/our-history/">Our History</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="http://localhost:8888/beulah/about/staff-directory/">Staff Directory</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sub-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-open .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  height: inherit;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".menu-item > a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("nav-open");
});
```

As of right now, the class is applied, when clicked, but on iPhone the dropdown does not open up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, iPad/iPhone click event is not triggered the way it is on your desktop.

You need to pick any of these events:

```
touchstart
touchmove
touchend
touchcancel
```

so, here :

```
$(".menu-item > a").bind( "touchstart" , function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().toggleClass("nav-open");
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. When I click it, nothing happens.

Comment: In addition, when click events are being triggered by dragging.